# ASP.NET MVC 3 SSO against ADAM and AD FS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, single-sign-on, adfs, adam

I read an article at this site about [ADAM, AD FS and SSO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262069%28v=office.12%29.aspx#section4)

Unfortunately I am not proficient in ADAM and AD FS, so I would like to know if I follow the "Web SSO with AD FS" part of this article then I can use SSO authentication against ADAM from an ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you refer to seems to be about AD FS 1.0, which is an older version and with which I have no experience.

As described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938662/223837), you use AD FS 2.0 only directly with Active Directory to authenticate users.  (You can use other sources for *authorization*.)  In other words, you cannot directly use it with ADAM (=LDS).

However, as that answer also describes, an alternative is to let AD FS redirect to a custom STS which you write yourself (e.g., on top of Windows Identity Foundation, WIF), which performs authentication against ADAM/LDS.

And [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088591/223837) has a brief description from someone who actually did this.